# Javascript clearInterval is not having an effect?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a simple redirect after x seconds on a page with a countdown timer. Every time I call the function I want the timer to be reset, however when i call it a second or third time the timer seems to have 3 different countdowns. Can anyone see why this is?

```
function delayRedirect(){
  document.getElementById('countDown').innerHTML = 'Session Timeout In: <span id="countTimer"></span> seconds....';
  clearInterval(sessionTimer);
  var sessionTimer = null;
  var timeleft = 60;
  var sessionTimer = setInterval(function(){
     timeleft--;
     document.getElementById('countTimer').innerHTML = timeleft;
     if(timeleft <= 0)
         clearInterval(sessionTimer);
         returnToLogin();
     },1000);
}
```

Comment: Well, you are creating a setInterval every time you call the `delayRedirect` function. Try to set that outside the function.

Comment: You have two `var sessionTimer = ...` in there. `var` is only used to declare a variable.

Comment: That is because i am trying to clear the previous one before starting it again

Comment: `sessionTimer` is a local variable in this function. Every time you call `delayRedirect`, value of `sessionTimer` is `null`. You need a global variable (or at least outer scope) to keep the sessionTimer id between the calls.

Comment: You need to declare `sessionTimer` *once*, outside the function.

Comment: @AKAust Editing the question with a solution that works is nonsense.

Comment: OK will put the before and after, sorry!

Comment: @AKAust Just leave it as it is; the after is below already, in the form of answers.

Comment: OK will leave as is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the sessionTimer globally. What you currently do is re-declare sessionTimer every time you enter delayRedirect.

Working example:

```js
const but = document.getElementById("but");
but.addEventListener("click", delayRedirect);

//define it globally
var sessionTimer = -1;

function delayRedirect() {
  //clear it if it previously exists
  clearInterval(sessionTimer);
  sessionTimer = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("sessionTimer " + sessionTimer);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button id="but">Run</button>
```

Comment: HI thanks for this, i just declared the variable outside the function and that worked. have updated my code which now works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I feel like all the answers only address the Y part, not the X part, given that this is clearly an XY problem.
While the solution is to use a variable that isn't local to the function, solving the actual problem doesn't require clearing anything. One can simply use an interval to tick down, and reset the count to delay the redirect:

```js
var timeleft = 60;

setInterval(function() {
  if (--timeleft === 0) returnToLogin();
  countTimer.innerHTML = timeleft;
}, 1000);

delay.onclick = function() {
  timeleft = 60;
}

function returnToLogin() {
  console.log("returning to login");
}
```

```html
<p>Session Timeout In: <span id="countTimer">60</span> seconds....</p>
<button id="delay">Delay</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well I had already accepted another but this is a nice way to do it!